# When is it safe to take my dog out to the park?

Tags: health, socializing, leash-training, dogs

My puppy is six weeks old and has only had her first vaccination. I want to start socialising her with other dogs and people, but don't want her to catch any nasty canine diseases.

When is it safe for me to take her to the dog park to socialise with other dogs, do I need to wait until she is fully vaccinated?

What other options are there to socialize my puppy before she is fully vaccinated?

A question that fits well with [How often and long should I walk my puppy?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-often-and-long-should-i-walk-my-puppy).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its always safe to wait till full vaccination.  Taking him to streets or parks is risky without full vaccination.

If you still want to socialize him before full vaccination, then you can make his interaction with known dogs that you know from the neighborhood etc which have had their full vaccination; either at your or their place. Avoid public places.

Comment: +1 Socialising them with a known dog in your home is a good option. Also, you can't be totally risk free, you might also be dragging in stuff on the soles of your shoes, etc.

Comment: @ThomasH it depends from person to person. My mom or sister not going to allow me to roam in shoes at all in house. So hygiene should be kept but we can't force it to anybody.